# DHCP logging with three Linksys E4200s

Tags: logging, dhcp, wifi

I have a small public WiFi network where I need to keep track of the number of monthly users. With a single Linksys E4200, I can use the firmware's DHCP client log. I dump the log and use a script to count the number of unique MAC addresses per day.

With three E4200s I haven't been able to do this. One router is connected to the modem. The other two are connected to the first router by Ethernet and are running in Cisco's [bridge mode](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/GetArticle.aspx?docid=02b368886e424d0daa9a756a75e86bc0_E4200_Frequently_Asked_Questions.xml&pid=8&converted=0#w), which basically turns them into access points. The problem is that this disables the logs on these routers, and the log on the first router seems to only display the wireless clients of *that* router.

Does anyone have suggestions for counting WiFi users? I imagine I could try another firmware. [This thread](http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/log-all-dhcp-clients-that-connect-on-tomato.31220/) seems to suggest that DHCP client logging is trivial in Tomato, but this is only for a single router, not my setup. Does anyone have any experience with a router and a couple APs using Tomato or DD-WRT? Is DHCP client logging possible in this situation? Is there a better solution (but using my current hardware) I'm missing?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Why not move DHCP to a centralized DHCP server?

Comment: Because our WiFi network isn't part of our actual network. The WAN link for WiFi is provided for free by a local ISP (since we're a public agency). There's literally just the modem and the routers. There aren't any computers on the network.

Comment: You could try getting them all to send logs to a syslog server but I'm not certain if the E4200 supports syslog and I'm not certain if the other two record DHCP events in syslog.

Comment: Hey @joeqwerty, I added a DHCP server to the network. It seemed like the easiest solution. If you want to add your comment as an answer to the question I'd be happy to choose it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Done and done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest moving the DHCP function to a centralized DHCP server.